# How to place the output of an echo statement and an arp statement on one line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, output

How can I get the output "echo" and "macaddress" on one line? 
This is what I've got:

```
ipRange="192.168.0."
macaddress= arp  | grep -w  "$ipRange$1" | awk '{print $3,$1}' 

ping -c1 "$ipRange$1" > /dev/null
         if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo  "deze host met mac address en ip address is up $macaddress"
else 
echo "het is down"
fi
```

This is the output:

```
VirtualBox ~ $ bash test2.sh 149
e0:b9:a5:f8:24:c3 192.168.0.149
deze host met mac address en ip address is up
```

Comment: provide a desired sample output/code

Comment: @Jahid deze host met mac address en ip address is up e0:b9:a5:f8:24:c3 192.168.0.149

Comment: @Jahid or if it is possible "de host met mac address: e0:b9:a5:f8:24:c3 en ip address:  192.168.0.149  is up"

Comment: `echo "de host met mac address: $macaddress en ip address: $ipRange$1 is up"` while changing `macaddress=...` to `macaddress=$(command)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `macaddress= arp  | grep -w  "$ipRange$1" | awk '{print $3,$1}'`

with `macaddress=$(arp | grep -w "$ipRange$1" | awk '{print $3,$1}')`

Comment: It might be a good idea to replace `grep -w` with `fgrep`, too.  Try this: `echo 1.2.3.4 | grep -qw 1.2.3. || echo nope`

Answer (score 2):

this should do output in single line

```
ipRange="192.168.0."
macaddress=$(arp  | grep -w  "$ipRange$1" | awk '{print $3,$1}')

ping -c1 "$ipRange$1" > /dev/null
         if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo  "deze host met mac address en ip address is up $macaddress"
else 
echo "het is down"
fi
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to replace `grep -w` with `fgrep`, too. Try this: `echo 1.2.3.4 | grep -qw 1.2.3. || echo nope`